# Ubuntu 20.10 on raspberry pi4. Recorded with Pi imager

Tags: software-installation

On a 4 GB raspberry Pi4, I can't install Ubuntu 20.10 on Pendrive. Yes on a 32GB micro SD but not on a 32GB pendrive. Leaves almost the entire pen blank. It only occupies one sector and thus it starts but then it is "hung".

Comment: It is stuck on the expanding the partition step I would think from that description. If you want I can show you instructions for the command line to create the partitions needed and then copy the files needed from your sd card to enable you to boot from the pen drive, Essentially cloning the card to the pen drive.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. I tried to increase the space with Gparted but it didn't work. You know how to do it ... thanks

Comment: Sure it is easy enough, the page below has the procedure. If this does not work then I can give you step by step procedure to copy all the files onto the disk we will create ourselves. It will be properly setup for you to use. If you had an install of the PiOS desktop you can do it with both the stick and the sdcard plugged into USB. There is tool called SD Card Imager I think is the name, That will clone from your card to the stick. You may want to try that if having second card laying around for it. https://jamesachambers.com/raspberry-pi-4-usb-boot-config-guide-for-ssd-flash-drives/